# split_to_table() by number of chars and no delimiter

Tags: regex, postgresql, split, pattern-matching, generate-series

I need to split a `varchar` field into lines of a set length, but there is no delimiter.

Example:
Filed value: `'Field example of varchar'`
And I want to split this into lines of length 5. The result should be:

```
"Field"
" exam"
"ple o"
"f var"
"char "
```

I have tried this query:

```
select regexp_split_to_table('Field example of varchar','(.{5})') as x
```

But it doesn't work, it returns five empty lines.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your regex anyway, almost: http://regex101.com/r/eP6zT1 -- you'll have to change {5} to {1,5} to catch the last entry since the string length does not seem to be evenly dividable by 5 (its 24).

Comment: The problem is, regexp_split_to_table retains data between separators, but not separators themselves. It would be interesting to see a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**`generate_series()`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-srf.html).
Should be substantially faster than [`regexp_matches()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-string.html), because regular expressions are powerful but *expensive*.

```
SELECT substring(col, generate_series(1, length(col), 5), 5)
FROM   tbl;
```

Note that you get *nothing* back for either of the presented solutions if the column is `NULL` or empty.

[**-> SQLfiddle** demonstrating both side by side.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/dc231/5)

Comment: strings are expensive too,

Answer (score 1):

You may use not **regexp_split_to_table**, but **regexp_matches**:

```
select (regexp_matches('Field example of varchar', E'.{1,5}', 'g'))[1]
```